# How to receive non-generic facebook profile pictures?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

i'm receiving that profile image picture now, i didn't change anything in my configuration (it worked fine before, and that user is me and i have a profile picture).

[image: generic facebook profile image]

```rb
# config/initializers/omniauth.rb

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider(
    :facebook,
    ENV.fetch("FACEBOOK_APP_ID"),
    ENV.fetch("FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET"),
    image_size: :large,
  )
end
```

```rb
# app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb

  def facebook
    uid = auth_hash["uid"]
    email = auth_hash["info"]["email"]
    image_url = auth_hash["info"]["image"]
    name = auth_hash["info"]["name"]
    first_name = name.split.first

    # ...
    attach_image_from_url(@user, image_url)
    # ...
  end

  private

  def auth_hash
    request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  end

  def attach_image_from_url(user, image_url)
    # return if user.image.attached?
    image = Down.download(image_url)
    user.image.attach(io: image, filename: "image.jpg")
  end
```

anything i'm missing ?

edit: i tried the setting the api version to 7.0 (it was 4.0) and it seems like the /picture endpoint has disappeared https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version4.0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to ominauth-facebook 8.0.0 (from 7.0.0) and setting `secure_image_url: true` fixed it

```rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider(
    :facebook,
    ENV.fetch("FACEBOOK_APP_ID"),
    ENV.fetch("FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET"),
    image_size: :large,
    secure_image_url: true,
  )
end
```

without `secure_image_url: true` i get a 500 error, see https://github.com/simi/omniauth-facebook/pull/346